# joda time, DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, date, jodatime

I have following code

```
dateTimeFormat = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis()
```

and i use dateTimeFormat below

```
public static String print(Date value) {
    return dateTimeFormat.print(value.getTime());
}
```

And now i get problem, in my print method i put many date instances with + 4 hours time, and after dateTimeFormat.print(value.getTime()); i get time with +3 hour, but one of all date instances become with +4 hours, this error  for me.

In all date instances has the same time zone Europe/Moscow

What may be wrong in my case?

Answer (score 2):

> In all date instances has the same time zone Europe/Moscow

A `Date` instance doesn't *have* a time zone - it's just an instant in time. But you should probably specify the time zone for your formatter, e.g.

```
dateTimeFormat = ISODateTimeFormat
    .dateTimeNoMillis()
    .withZoneUTC();
```

If you want a value which *does* know about a time zone, you should use `DateTime` instead of `Date`.

Comment: Aftet this option i dont see my + x hours in my soap responce

    <ns2:openDate>2014-09-17T00:00:00Z</ns2:openDate>

what code help me show my + x hours?

Comment: @user3569530: Well what zone do you want to use? As I said, a Date doesn't have a zone...

Answer (score 2):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Also, quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(print(new Date()));
    }

    public static String print(Date value) {
        return value.toInstant()
                .atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Moscow"))
                .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS)
                .toOffsetDateTime()
                .toString();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-06-20T16:18:56+03:00
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/0U8jh1)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>